# Is there a way to dynamically implement API interface classes in kotlin with bytebuddy? (Mixins pattern)

Tags: kotlin, casting, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

Let me summerize what I am trying to achieve. Basically I want a way to have a set of interfaces which server an an api that external plugins use to interact with the engine.

Here is how I currently have things setup.

```
class Engine : ApiEngine {

    override fun start() {
        println("Starting Engine")
    }

    override fun stop() {
        println("Stopping Engine.")
    }
}
```

```
interface ApiEngine {

    fun start()

    fun stop()

}
```

This is cumbersome and I have seen some other solutions using ASM and injecting the interface dynamically into the "Engine" class. I have seen something like this in another source but never could fully figure out how to do.

```
@Implements("ApiEngine")
class Engine {

    @Export("start")
    fun start() {
        println("Starting Engine")
    }

    @Export("stop")
    fun stop() {
        println("Stopping Engine.")
    }
}
```

```
interface ApiEngine {

    @Import("start")
    fun start()

    @Import("stop")
    fun stop()

}
```

My question is, in ByteBuddy, is it possible to effively make `Engine` implement `ApiEngine` so that it an instance of Engine() can be cast to ApiEngine for API usage?

Comment: I think you may want to go for something else other than inheritance. If all you want is for `Engine` to implement `ApiEngine`, then what is stopping you from doing this at compile time?

Comment: Assuming you don't have access to `ApiEngine` before compile time, and you somehow manage to change the bytecode of the `Engine` instance to also behave as `ApiEngine`, then there is also the problem of knowing what methods `ApiEngine` have in order that `Engine` should also provide definitions for those methods. Please add more details to your question

Comment: If it is the case that these external plugins know about this interface, then maybe the best way to go about this is to use dependency injection to inject an instance of `ApiEngine` into `Engine`. If you really want your `Engine` to behave as `ApiEngine`, then in addition to DI, you can use Kotlin's builtin delegate pattern to achieve this. Groovy is also another language that supports this kind of delegation

Comment: smac89 Do you have any info on this. I have been using Koin for dependency injection an I know that it has the bind feature. Reguarding the delegation pattern in kotlin, I have look at this before but could never find any information about how to do this.

Basically, if I have `ApiEngine` interface in its own separate module from `Engine`, I dont want to have to implement the api module into the engine. I want them to be separate.

Comment: What I was suggesting was this: `class Engine (val apiEngine: ApiEngine): ApiEngine by apiEngine`, and this means that `Engine` will implement `ApiEgine`, but because of delegation, it will already have all the properties of `ApiEngine`. I'm not sure if this is what you want because your last comment says you don't wnat to implement the api module, but your question was asking how to also cast `Engine` to `ApiEngine`. It seems to me that if you want to be able to cast one to the other, you need inheritance for that to work and I'm not sure what magic bytebuddy will provide to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible. You can for example integrate Byte Buddy as a build tool where you generate interfaces upon discovery. Simply implement the `Plugin` interface and match types based on your annotation being present.

As a next step, you would need to instrument those types to implement an additional interface using the `DynamicType.Builder` DSL that Byte Buddy provides you. If your methods always match their signature, there is nothing more to be done since Byte Buddy automatically detects those overrides. If the method signatures can vary, you would need to implement the interface methods using `MethodCall` to implement a delegation to the actual implementation.